# Google Adsense - policy violation on page without ads

Tags: google-adsense-policies

Adsense is currently listing a page-level "Copyrighted material (DMCA)" violation against my site. The page it refers to is a search result listing page, so maybe one of the results at one time was enough for someone to complain.

The strange thing is that I removed Adsense from these search results over a year ago. The policy center says there were hundreds of ad displays on this page the past 7 days, while Google Analytics says it receives *hundreds of thousands* of page views, so Adsense thinks some tiny fraction of users are seeing ads there. Perhaps some proxy, browser extension, or other thing is messing with the page; I don't know.

I can't submit a review for this policy violation - the policy center says "We found some policy violations in your content that you must fix. These types of violations require a different review process.", and links to https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/7003627, which describes the normal review UI which is not present for this violation.

Normally for DMCA things, I'd remove the content, but this is a search result page, I don't know what content it's complaining about. I've taken out the ads, but Adsense still thinks they're there sometimes. I can't submit a review. I'm concerned that leaving it as is will result in some site-wide action being taken. How do I resolve this violation?

Comment: Are you sure the site has not been hacked?

Comment: I'm about as sure as you can be about such things. Why someone would hack the site just to show my own ads on a tiny fraction of traffic anyway?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Out of my ~3000 pages, one has a woman in bikini, so after a warning, I removed all javascript and references to google from that single page, but years later I still get regular "Restricted ad serving" warnings for that page.